# rails 6 error messages not working with sign in/sign up modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using devise to handle registration with username/email and facebook.  Everything is working except error messages.  If I try to login from the modal and enter the wrong email or password, it doesn't do anything, but I can't figoure out how to get the error messages to appear in the modal form.

If I close the modal after an error and reopen it there are no errors and I'm not sure how to refresh the modal. If it is successfulit logs me in and takes me to my profile page, but if it is not succesful it just sits there. I'm not sure how to open it without clicking a link.

If I submit the registragion form with no or missing info it will go back to the regular sign up page and display the errors but I can't figure out how to hvae it reload the modal and display them there.

Here is the _login.html.erb model:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="login" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="login" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg border-0">
    <div class="modal-content border-0">
      <div class="modal-content-head">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="login">Member Login</h5>  
        <button type="button" class="close text-right" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
            <div class="row border-0">
              <div class="col-12 modal-content-subhead">
                Login
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col modal-content">
               
                <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name), :remote => true) do |f| %>
                  <%= render "shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
                  
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_email.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Email", :autofocus => true %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_locked.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Password" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
                    <div>
                      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me, class: "form_small_text" %>
                    </div>
                  <% end -%>
                  <div class="form-group row text-center">
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <%= f.submit "Sign in", :class => 'btn reg-submit-btn' %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <%- if devise_mapping.recoverable? && controller_name != 'passwords' && controller_name != 'registrations' %>
                      <%= link_to t(".forgot_your_password"), new_password_path(resource_name), class: "form_small_text" %><br />
                    <% end -%>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-1 text-center p-0">
            <%= image_tag("layout/login/login_divider.gif") %>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
            <div class="row border-0">
              <div class="col-12 modal-content-subhead">
                Sign-Up
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col modal-content">
                <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), id: "form", :remote => true) do |f| %>
                  <%= render "shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>
                  
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_name_37_33.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "First Name" %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Last Name" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_email.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Email", :autofocus => true %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <div class="reg_tooltip" data-tooltip="
                        The club username will be used to easily share your club page on this website.  
                        For example if your club username is my_club the url for your club page on this 
                        site will be www.themathouse.com/clubs/my_club.
                        ">
                        <svg width="1em" height="1em" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-question-diamond" fill="white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                          <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M6.95.435c.58-.58 1.52-.58 2.1 0l6.515 6.516c.58.58.58 1.519 0 2.098L9.05 15.565c-.58.58-1.519.58-2.098 0L.435 9.05a1.482 1.482 0 0 1 0-2.098L6.95.435zm1.4.7a.495.495 0 0 0-.7 0L1.134 7.65a.495.495 0 0 0 0 .7l6.516 6.516a.495.495 0 0 0 .7 0l6.516-6.516a.495.495 0 0 0 0-.7L8.35 1.134z"/>
                          <path d="M5.255 5.786a.237.237 0 0 0 .241.247h.825c.138 0 .248-.113.266-.25.09-.656.54-1.134 1.342-1.134.686 0 1.314.343 1.314 1.168 0 .635-.374.927-.965 1.371-.673.489-1.206 1.06-1.168 1.987l.003.217a.25.25 0 0 0 .25.246h.811a.25.25 0 0 0 .25-.25v-.105c0-.718.273-.927 1.01-1.486.609-.463 1.244-.977 1.244-2.056 0-1.511-1.276-2.241-2.673-2.241-1.267 0-2.655.59-2.75 2.286zm1.557 5.763c0 .533.425.927 1.01.927.609 0 1.028-.394 1.028-.927 0-.552-.42-.94-1.029-.94-.584 0-1.009.388-1.009.94z"/>
                        </svg>
                      </div>
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_name_37_33.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Username", id: "username" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_locked.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.password_field :password, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Password" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                    
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 col-form-label p-2">
                      <%= image_tag("layout/login/icon_reg_locked.gif") %>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
                      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: "form-control shadow rounded", placeholder: "Confirm Password" %>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group row text-center">
                    <div class="col-12">
                      <%= f.submit "Sign up", :class => 'btn reg-submit-btn' %></div></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                <% end %>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-11 text-center">
              <%=link_to( image_tag("layout/facebook_login_200_42.gif"), user_facebook_omniauth_authorize_path) %>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the applicatin_helpers.rb file:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end
    
  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end
    
  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end
end
```

Both forms in the modal work. I can sign up with email/password or facebok and I can create an account and log in but I can't get the errors to show up in the modal.

Comment: well those errors will only appear when the page refreshes with this setup (is my guess).  When you submit with an error does the page refresh?  Is so, if you open the modal again are the errors showing?

Comment: If I close the modal after an error and reopen it there are no errors and I'm not sure how to refresh the modal.  If it is successfulit logs me in and takes me to my profile page, but if it is not succesful it just sits there.  I'm not sure how to open it without clicking a link.

Comment: Sorry, if I submit the sign up form it will go back to the regular devise sign uppage and display errors but I don't know how to reload the modal with those errors.

Comment: Can you update the question with that information?  Just in general it will help if you get some useful suggestions if you provide information on what exactly is happening.

Comment: I edited the guestion.  Thanks,